# Two progress bars with separate updates

Tags: python, progress-bar

I would like to have a loading bar for an application, but said application has large pauses so I would also like an indicator that the process has not died even if the loading bar does not fill for a while.

Using the python progressbar library I came up with this.

```
import progressbar
import time

loopval=20

bar = progressbar.ProgressBar(maxval=loopval,widgets[progressbar.Bar(marker='#',fill='.',\
left='[',right=']'),progressbar.AnimatedMarker(), progressbar.Percentage()])

bar.start()

for i in range(loopval):
   bar.update(i+1)
   time.sleep(0.1)
```

This prints out a nice looking bar of '.''s that slowly fills with '#''s and has an accurate percentage at the end of the line as well as a rotating animated marker.

ex:
[############################################################################]/100%
(the slash at the end goes between |,/,-,and \)

I would like to be able to update the animated marker separately from the bar update. This way even if the bar does not update for a while the animated marker will show that the process is still alive.

I have looked through the progressbar docs and could't find a way to do this. I am not married to this library if there is a better one that makes this easier I am happy to switch as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but I managed to do this by wrapping your code with asyncio.  I increased the sleep between updates to 1 second to make the asynchronous updates more obvious.  Hope this helps.

```
# Python 3.6+
import asyncio
import progressbar

async def update_bar(bar):
    while not bar.end_time:
        bar.update()
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

async def iterate_bar(bar, loopval):
    bar.start()
    for i in range(loopval):
        bar.update(i+1)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    bar.finish()

async def main(bar, loopval):
    await asyncio.gather(update_bar(bar), iterate_bar(bar, loopval))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loopval = 20
    bar = progressbar.ProgressBar(
        maxval=loopval,
        widgets=[
            progressbar.Bar(
                marker='#',
                fill='.',
                left='[',
                right=']',
            ),
            progressbar.AnimatedMarker(),
            progressbar.Percentage(),
        ],
    )

    asyncio.run(main(bar, loopval))
```

Comment: Okay so this does look like it would solve my problem, however I failed to mention that I am stuck using python 3.5, do you know how to alter the asyncio section to work in that version?

Comment: It's been a while since I've used earlier Python version, so take this with a grain of salt, but I believe the code should still work in 3.5 as that was the version "async def" was introduced; I just can't guarantee the behavior.  To be safe, you can look into the `@asyncio.coroutine` function decorator to replace the `async def` blocks.  Here's something a quick Google search yielded me: https://snarky.ca/how-the-heck-does-async-await-work-in-python-3-5/
I'm on holiday so I can't readily create a 3.5 venv to test this for you unfortunately.  Hope that helps!